# Double Y axis ticks for Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to set ticks for a double y-axis line graph but either the graph wont load, it it loads exactly the same. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Goal is to set Price ticks: [0.002, 0.004. 0.006. 0.008], and Volume increment by lets say 1000

Also having issues with prices for instance being: 0.00242, 0.00521 all showing up as 0.1

```html
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Timestamp, LastPrice, Volume FROM vol";
$result = $dbconnect->query($sql);
?> 
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   
   
           google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var button = document.getElementById('change-chart');
      var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    
    
    
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Timestamp','LastPrice','Volume'],
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "[           '".$row["Timestamp"]."', ".$row["LastPrice"].", ".$row["Volume"].",    ],";
                    }
     echo $row["LastPrice"];
                ?>
        ]);

        var materialOptions = {
   
  chart: {
          
        },
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
  
        series: {
          // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
          0: {axis: 'LastPrice' },
          1: {axis: 'BaseVolume'}
        },
  
  vAxis: {1: {ticks:[0, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006]} },
  
        axes: {
          // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
          y: {
            LastPrice: {label: 'Price'}, 
            BaseVolume: {label: 'Volume'}
   
          }
        }
  
      };

     

      function drawMaterialChart() {
        var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
        materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
        button.innerText = 'Classic';
        button.onclick = drawClassicChart;
      }


      drawMaterialChart();

    }
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are several configuration options that aren't supported by *Material* charts, including...

`{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.ticks`

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

instead, recommend using a *Classic* chart with the following option...

`theme: 'material'`

---

for dual y-axis charts, use the `series` option to specify the target axis

```
  series: {
    1: {
      targetAxisIndex: 1,
    }
  },
```

use option `vAxes`, with an **e**, to specify `ticks` for each y-axis

```
  vAxes: {
    0: {
      ticks:[0, 1000, 2000, 3000],
      title: 'Last Price'
    },
    1: {
      ticks:[0, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006],
      title: 'Base Volume'
    }
  }
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'x', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'y0', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'y1', type: 'number'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'row 0'}, {v: 1800}, {v: 0.00242}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 1'}, {v: 2200}, {v: 0.00521}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 2'}, {v: 2800}, {v: 0.00343}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 3'}, {v: 2800}, {v: 0.00441}]},
        {c:[{v: 'row 4'}, {v: 2300}, {v: 0.00532}]}
      ]
    });

    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, {
      width: 600,
      height: 300,
      series: {
        1: {
          targetAxisIndex: 1,
        }
      },
      theme: 'material',
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          ticks:[0, 1000, 2000, 3000],
          title: 'Last Price'
        },
        1: {
          ticks:[0, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006],
          title: 'Base Volume'
        }
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Mate you are a legend, worked like a treat and it made so much sense

Comment: Do have one more question if that is ok, my data is being represented properly on the Y axis, but when I hover over it is rounding up everything up instead of leaving it for price, so instead of 0.00492123 it would be 0.005 and for 0.005213 it would also just show 0.005. Any help will be greatly aprpeciated, thanks!

Comment: Found the answer, posting for anyone else that stumbles on this

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 15
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);


Thanks again!