# Google Material Line Chart - Ticks

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, material-design, linechart

When using "Cassic" Line chart I can assign the ticks for the hAxis, also the format and title like this:

```
var options = {
    hAxis: {
    format:'h a',
    title: 'Time',
    ticks: [...range...]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same when using the Material Line chart?

So far I have been able to set the title:

```
var options = {
    axes: {
      x: {
        0: {label: 'Time'}
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are several options that are not supported by _material_ charts, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- which includes: `{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.ticks` -- there is an option for _classic_ charts to render __similar__ to _material_ --> `theme: 'material'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double Y axis ticks for Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541286/double-y-axis-ticks-for-google-charts)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to assign the ticks because I needed to set the start and the end to specific dates, I found another way to accomplish that when using the material line chart:

```
var lineChartOptions = {
    chart: {
        title: 'Chart Title'
    },
    axes: {
        y: {
            0: { label: 'Label 1' },
        },
        x: {
            0: { label: 'Label 2' },
            all: {
                range: {
                    max: new Date(...),
                    min: new Date(...)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: { position: 'left' }
};
```

This worked for me.